# How to move existing business catalyst site to different account without becoming a partner

Tags: migration, business-catalyst

I have an existing business catalyst website on a partner account I need to relocate to a different account, that is not a partner account because I cannot afford the $900 partner fee. Any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Comment: Why the down-vote? I grant that the question doesn't show research, but it is clear and is something that may be useful to others in future as finding this info is difficult if you're not already a BC Partner.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't transfer a Business Catalyst site to a non-paid Partner Portal. However, you can transfer to a paid Partner Portal and I can help with that.

I'm a BC Partner and would be happy to have your site transferred to my Partner Portal (account). I'm a Standard Partner which means the billing relationship for your website remains between you and Adobe - has nothing to do with me - and the subscription plan you choose is up to you.

It's a relatively straightforward process. You need to sign into the Admin area and go to *Help & Support*. From there, either start a chat or submit a ticket.

You will need to provide the following info:

- your user email
- the new Partner name
- the new Partner URL
- the new Partner email

(details here: http://helpx.adobe.com/business-catalyst/partner-portal/transferring-sites-partners.html)

And that's it. The owner of your current Partner Portal (you) will also need to verify that they consent to the site being moved - BC may require you to submit an additional ticket from the Help & Support tab in your Partner Portal.

I can provide you will all my contact details and required info. Just go to my site: http://www.indieweb.co.nz/contact and flick me a webform enquiry.

I look forward to hearing from you.

Cheers,
Luke